# How to rotate rectangle which fits in a circle in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geometry

I have a circle (in code its called "cyc_166_1")  located at a certain angle with regard to another point.
I would like to draw a rectangle which both fits in that second circle (bounds within it), and has the same rotation angle.
How is it possible to do that?

```
var sainteAgathe_166_cyclic = L.circle([44.7105555555556, 6.84916666666667], 750, {fillColor:'none', color: '#404040', weight: 0.8, opacity: 1,}).addTo(map);     
var length = 0.007
var angle = 55    
var end_x = sainteAgathe_166_cyclic.getLatLng().lng + length * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)
var end_y = sainteAgathe_166_cyclic.getLatLng().lat + length * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
var cyc_166_1 = L.circle([end_y, end_x], 90, {fillColor:'#800026', fillOpacity: 1, color: '#800026', weight: 0.5, opacity: 1}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you multiply each point with this matrix:

```
| cos(x) -sin(x) 0 |
| sin(x)  cos(x) 0 |  * (lat, lng, 1)
| 0        0     1 |
```

you should get new set of coords (lat, lng) which represent the rotated rect